# Different authorization for views and api in ASP.NET Core application

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, windows-authentication

I have to create an Intranet website using Windows Authentication. Some of our employees should use this site to review some data comming through an public facing api. This api provides POST actions to receive data from field workers with an android app written by our company too.

Am I wrong that all appliances of authentication, like Windows Authentication, is generally app- global? Is it possible to provide Auth X for all HTML views and Authentication Y for all api actions?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

In Asp.NET Core you can apply authorization at the global, controller, or action level.  This should give you enough freedom to setup authorization however you want.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/views

Comment: That sounds great but since I enabled Windows Authentication through IIS it's enabled on all actions.

Comment: Edit: I talking about authentication rather than authorization. I know I could apply role- or claim based policies on controller or actions but how about different authentication like Windows for html or jwt for rest?